# Highscore in endless runner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know why the highscore isn't this working?
In game, the score system works but the highscore isn't. I've tried many ways to make it work, but it doesn't.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform jugador;
    public Text Score;
    public Text highscore;
    public Text scoreText;
    private int currentscore = 0;
    private float floa;


    void Start() {

        highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();
    }
    private void SetHighScore() {

        if (currentscore > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0)) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", currentscore);
        }
    }
    private void Update () {

        floa = jugador.position.z;
        currentscore = (int)floa;
        scoreText.text = currentscore.ToString();
        highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("HighScore").ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: You never call `SetHighScore`?

Comment: when you die, make sure you call `SetHighScore()`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `GetInt` in `Update` all the time over and over again ... Would be enough to get it **once** on app start and later only update it **once** again if the Highscore was actually changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highscore is working but when you use it on the `highscore.text` you are calling a `PlayerPrefs.GetString` but the Highscore it's actually an integer!
Just change the last line in this way:

```
highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore",0).ToString();
```

It should be fine :D

Answer (score -3):

highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("HighScore").ToString();

above line is wrong it should be

highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore",0).ToString();

becasue when you save score PlayerPrefs is Int type not the string.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069192/7111561)